# jquery if input text has value, add class to label, remove it if no value

Tags: jquery

I'm sure there are many similar questions here but still i can't find an answer to this. What i want is to add a class to the label on document ready if the input[type="text"] has a value and remove that class if the user will delete that input value ( better said, remove the label class if the input has no value on blur ).

Code so far:

```
    <div class="input-wrap">            
                <input type="text" name="textdemo" id="textdemo" size="20" value="" class="textdemo" />
            <label class="demo-label" for="textdemo">{L_USERNAME}</label>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input-wrap .textdemo').val() ) {
          $('label.demo-label').addClass('input-has-value');
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
function checkForInput(element) {
  // element is passed to the function ^
  
  const $label = $(element).siblings('label');

  if ($(element).val().length > 0) {
    $label.addClass('input-has-value');
  } else {
    $label.removeClass('input-has-value');
  }
}

// The lines below are executed on page load
$('input.textdemo').each(function() {
  checkForInput(this);
});

// The lines below (inside) are executed on change & keyup
$('input.textdemo').on('change keyup', function() {
  checkForInput(this);  
});
```

```css
label.input-has-value {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" name="textdemo" id="textdemo" size="20" value="" class="textdemo" />
  <label class="demo-label" for="textdemo">{L_USERNAME}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working but i want to check if the input has value on document ready as well. How can i do that please?

Comment: and i should replace $(element) with $('input.textdemo') ? as i want to check only the input with that class.

Comment: No, element is the variable that is passed to the function. Check the lines below the "Page load" comment. This is executed on page load. I've updated the comments to make it a little more clear.

Comment: It works but, I have 1 issue when chrome autofill is there, then it's not working... I mean, it's not detecting that it  is auto fill there or not....  So, what to do????

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the input has a value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.input-wrap .textdemo').val() !='' ) {
          $('label.demo-label').addClass('input-has-value');
    }
    $('.input-wrap .textdemo').blur(function(){
        if($('.input-wrap .textdemo').val() !='' ) {
          $('label.demo-label').addClass('input-has-value');
        }else{
          $('label.demo-label').removeClass('input-has-value');
        }   
    }
});
```